# datatable rowcount

Tags: asp.net

My datatable's rowcount property is returning decimal values.
Any idea why?

```
dtTempTable.Rows.Count 
0x00001019
```

Comment: Since the Count property is typed as an int, the only way to have it return a decimal is if it being converted to one. E.g., `decimal foo = dTempTable.Rows.Count;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First 0x00001019 is not decimal, but hexadecimal. (the prefix 0x indicate thant number is **displayed** in is hexadecimal form.)

It's just the representation of the data, if you compare it to a decimal value or convert it to a string, it will "work" as it's supposed.

If it display it through the watch windows or something like this, you could [uncheck hexadecimal display](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/10/14/the-watch-window-hexadecimal-display-vstiptool0110.aspx) (you could also do it though the [General, Debugging, Options Dialog Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85yzd16c%28VS.71%29.aspx) depending of your version of visual studio)